# How to correctly config a Google Functions Framework with Go inside a Firebase app

Tags: firebase, go, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing an app in Flutter, and I want to be supported by Firebase and Google Cloud Functions: I can't use Firebase Functions since I'm planning to write Functions in Go.

At the moment my project's folder looks like this:

- `./lib/`
- `./functions/`

  - `myFunc1/`
  - `myFunc2/`
  - ...
- [other files and folders...]

Inside `./lib/` lies my Dart source codes.

Inside `./functions/`, as you can see, I'm planning to create a folder for each go Function.

Inside a single './myFunc1/' folder, there's a `.go` file (my function), the `go.mod` file and the `go.sum` file.

Now, it looks like that the Go extension in VS code show me errors that don't make sense to me. Whenever I try to do a `go mod tidy`, I get the following error: "Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.sum needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error".

If I run the command manually (without the extension), nothing happens (no errors are shown in the terminal) and I still get a visual red squiggle. If I run my main.go test file manually, everything is just OK.

I have no clue what's this about, I just want to start deploying my function without the whole folder being red-colored and error-flagged by the VS code extension and I have no idea what to do to solve this.

**EDIT**. Here's my VS Code's `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-darker",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme",
    "dart.debugExternalLibraries": false,
    "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "[go]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true
    },
}
```

Comment: Vscode expects your module to be in the root. Have you tried adding each individual function folder to your workspace? That may solve your issue.

Comment: @Cadet Hi there, I just tried, doesn't change a thing: I still get this "loading error" _PLUS_ I get another error: "Command 'gopls.tidy' failed: Error: All files must be saved first." (obviously all of my files are saved...)

Comment: can you share your vscode settings (anything that includes "go" or "gopls")?  From the go issue tracker, I see a couple of issues related to experimental workspace module, but not sure if yours is the same case.

Comment: @Hana Sure thing, I edited my question... I'm desperate at this point, I can't wrap my head around these settings and I lost 2 days already

Comment: Sorry that you have to go through this issue.

I suspected experimental workspace module setting but it doesn't seem like you have the settings. 
Can you open an issue in github.com/golang/vscode-go ? Please attach the gopls log (you can redact any file contents or sensitive file names if any) to the issue. The instruction is https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#collect-extension-logs

Comment: Hello there, I'm sorry that I didn't see you message before. As I said I was pretty desperate, so here's what I did: I uninstalled go and vs code. Then, I fully cleaned everything + re-installed back everything. At that point I still got the error, and therefore I just added the following to  `settings.json`: `"gopls": {"experimentalWorkspaceModule": true}`... and... poof! It just works, no errors. I'm confused. And more importantly, I can't reproduce an error so I can file it to a github issue...